# How can I get uget downloads to start immediately?

Tags: uget

In uget, when I click on a link it shows me all the details of that download, and then if I confirm it, the download gets queued.

From the queue if I tap the green start button, the download still doesn't start.

So to start any download I have to force start them manually.

How can I make the downloads start immediately without getting in the queue?

Comment: Presumably there's some setting in the configuration of uget.

Answer (score 2):

In the "*all the details of that download*" window, make sure "*Runnable*" (instead of "*Pause*") is selected under "Status".

Also, the "*green start button*" starts/resumes only the *selected* download(s), not the whole queue.

Comment: Even if I select runnable the download doesn't start.it just stays paused in "Queuing",and from the queue if i tap the green start button,the download stays paused in queue until i force start it.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/mLusGkX3j0jEduYJ3
here i made a really quick video doing everything you said.
the download just wont start until i force start it.
the green button just sits like it has no functionality.
where am i doing wrong? 

and thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @jongla Hmm... that doesn't look right, seems to be a bug. What's your uGet version? I would suggest you to try the latest stable version of uGet from its [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~plushuang-tw/+archive/ubuntu/uget-stable).

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable from website.Will reinstall then.

Comment: That is very very weird. I have never seen such a bug in the app before. We just released a new version of uGet with a ton of new features and bug fixes. Please try the new version 2.2.0 and test this again. If it continues that is something I certainly would like to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell I did all the following: 
1.installed 2.2.0 over current installation 
2.purged uget,aria2 and reinstalled 
3.removed config folder from home directory

but none of them solves it.
And another thing,after removing the home config folder,the list of files and settings do not reset,i dont know if its normal so I included it.


Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select **Settings** from **Edit** menu.
2. Select **Others** tab from **Settings**.
3. Check **Use '--quiet' by default**